# Adding sparse vectors in Apache Spark efficiently

Tags: apache-spark, scala-breeze

The latest release of spark uses breeze for vectors.

There are no operations available for adding the vectors  [org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)

I need to convert them to arrays and add.But the efficiency is lost.

In the source code of spark the vectors are converted to breeze vector (breeze.linalg.Vector) by toBreeze function and then added.

But toBreeze is a private function and cant be used.
So what is the best method to add vectors? Please help ..

Comment: I've run into a similar issue with dot products.  Wondering if these features are intentionally omitted or just not implemented yet.

Comment: yeah, I found that using python we can use those vector operations but in scala there is no such operation. Just don't understand why.